# Community Promotion Ads Mistake

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

All of the posts on SE sites that show for Community Promo ads have the same dialog for what to use for the post:

```
    [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

       [1]: http://image-url
       [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

The problem is that the part that says "Tagline to show on mouseover" is **not** the tagline!
That is the alt text!!!
The tagline goes in quotes after the link url!

So it should be:

```
    [![Alt text][1]][2]

       [1]: http://image-url "Tagline to show on mouseover"
       [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Yes, I know I can edit each of these posts individually, but the general template for creating these posts should be changed.